# Ssh 'access denied' from one host but not the other

Tags: debian, ssh, authentication

Consider the following scenario:

I have a Debian-ssh-server setup and exposed it to the internet for some time for testing. Also I have an account which is basically configured as root in the `sudoers` file (I know this is poorly mis-configured!) and of course no root login is permitted. The authentication is password and not key based.

What happened is the following, I have set up the server from my own laptop and I could login to this account from anywhere, at home of course and even from other networks. But as I tried to login from another machine I got the 'access denied' message.

What grinds my gears is why could I login from my home machine, the access should have been denied either, shouldn't it?

Comment: if your client a command line client execute it with command ssh -vvvvvvv it will give very understandable output to know which authentication is used

Answer (score 2):

Open the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change the next line:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

with:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Finally, reboot the server.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at multiple things:

1. Look at the log files on the server: `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/secure`  as [Jenny](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21109/jenny-d) did propose in her [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109574/ssh-access-denied-from-one-host-but-not-the-other/109577#comment169041_109577).
2. Configuration of your ssh ( `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on your client machine ), it might be set not to use password authentication ( entyr `PasswordAuthentication` set to `no`).
3. Start `ssh` with `-v` option (`ssh -v`) to get verbose output
4. Configuration of the sshd ( `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ) on the server. It could only listen to connections coming from certain IP addresses ( e.g. the one from you router ).

If you can, try to login from the client to another machine, that way you can pinpoint which of both machines is the problem (although they might be both the problem).

Comment: I'd add a third thing: Look at the sshd logs on the server. Where they are will depend on how syslog is setup on the server; common places are `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: @JennyD Uh, yes of course %-) Should/can I include that in the answer (with attribution of course), so it is less easy to overlook?

Comment: @Timo Yes, generally you should. I usually add links to both the comment (the timestamp is a link!) as well as the user's profile page when I do, and have never had anyone complain.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thank you. I got baffled that in edit screen  you don't have the comments to reference anymore. Had to close, open edit in another window ...

Comment: What I forgot to mention is, that I could login from the other machine, after I changed the sudoers configuration. I added my account to the sudoers group and deleted it from the sudoers file.